# x2go login terminated immediately for one user only

Tags: login, x2go

I was trying to use my x2go client on a pc to login into a ubuntu desktop.

After login, the session was terminated immediately. I have access to two other accounts and they both login find. Putty ssh of the problematic account and all other accounts worked fine as well.

Here is the .Xsession-error output:

```
      GNU nano 4.8                                                                                                                                                               .xsession-errors.old                                                                                                                                                                Modified  
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1001/bus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/mnt/md0/brandi/.Xauthority
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SHELL=/bin/bash
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-xubuntu:/etc/xdg
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting CLUTTER_BACKEND=x11
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LANGUAGE=en_US
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting MESA_LOADER_DRIVER_OVERRIDE=i965
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DESKTOP_SESSION=xubuntu
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PWD=/mnt/md0/brandi
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=xubuntu
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LOGNAME=brandi
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=gtk2
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GPG_AGENT_INFO=/run/user/1001/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/mnt/md0/brandi/.Xauthority
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/lightdm-data/brandi
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GDM_LANG=en_US
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting HOME=/mnt/md0/brandi
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting IM_CONFIG_PHASE=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LANG=en_US.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=XFCE
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_OVERLAY_SCROLLING=0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting USER=brandi
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SHLVL=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1001
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/xfce4:/usr/share/xubuntu:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GDMSESSION=xubuntu
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1001/bus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting _=/usr/bin/dbus-update-activation-environment
/usr/bin/iceauth:  creating new authority file /run/user/1001/ICEauthority
libGL error: failed to create dri screen
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: failed to create dri screen
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965

(xfwm4:2662): xfwm4-WARNING **: 15:06:43.920: Unsupported GL renderer (llvmpipe (LLVM 12.0.0, 256 bits)).
** (wrapper-2.0:2791): WARNING **: 15:06:44.327: No outputs have backlight property
(wrapper-2.0:2791): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:06:44.368: Negative content width -3 (allocation 1, extents 2x2) while allocating gadget (node button, owner PowerManagerButton)
(wrapper-2.0:2793): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:06:44.370: Negative content width -3 (allocation 1, extents 2x2) while allocating gadget (node button, owner PulseaudioButton)
(wrapper-2.0:2786): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:06:44.394: Theme parsing error: <data>:1:46: The style property GtkWidget:focus-padding is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version
(wrapper-2.0:2786): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:06:44.394: Theme parsing error: <data>:1:78: The style property GtkWidget:focus-line-width is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version
(wrapper-2.0:2786): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:06:44.394: Theme parsing error: <data>:1:108: The style property GtkButton:default-border is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version
(wrapper-2.0:2786): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:06:44.394: Theme parsing error: <data>:1:136: The style property GtkButton:inner-border is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version
Tracker-Message: 15:06:44.397: Set scheduler policy to SCHED_IDLE
Tracker-Message: 15:06:44.397: Setting priority nice level to 19

(polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1:2866): GLib-CRITICAL **: 15:06:44.415: g_variant_new_string: assertion 'string != NULL' failed
(polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1:2866): polkit-gnome-1-WARNING **: 15:06:44.416: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
Tracker-Message: 15:06:44.439: Set scheduler policy to SCHED_IDLE
Tracker-Message: 15:06:44.439: Setting priority nice level to 19

(wrapper-2.0:2785): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 15:06:44.441: g_file_new_for_path: assertion 'path != NULL' failed
(wrapper-2.0:2785): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 15:06:44.441: g_file_monitor_file: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
(wrapper-2.0:2785): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 15:06:44.441: invalid (NULL) pointer instance
(wrapper-2.0:2785): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 15:06:44.441: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
(wrapper-2.0:2785): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:06:44.441: Attempting to add a widget with type GtkToggleButton to a container of type XfcePanelPlugin, but the widget is already inside a container of type XfcePanelPlugin, please remove the widget from its existing container first.
(wrapper-2.0:2786): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:06:44.457: Theme parsing error: <data>:1:46: The style property GtkWidget:focus-padding is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version
(wrapper-2.0:2786): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:06:44.457: Theme parsing error: <data>:1:78: The style property GtkWidget:focus-line-width is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version
(wrapper-2.0:2786): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:06:44.457: Theme parsing error: <data>:1:108: The style property GtkButton:default-border is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version
(wrapper-2.0:2786): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:06:44.457: Theme parsing error: <data>:1:136: The style property GtkButton:inner-border is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version
(tracker-miner-fs:2862): Tracker-CRITICAL **: 15:06:44.471: Could not request DBus name 'org.freedesktop.Tracker1.Miner.Files': D-Bus service name:'org.freedesktop.Tracker1.Miner.Files' is already taken, perhaps the application is already running?
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Please edit and format the pasted output as `code` using the {_} icon above the edit window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it is the .bashrc paths that got messed up after switching from anaconda3 to miniconda. Once the paths are corrected, the user login issue was resolved.